# To do a spoiler or to spoiler?

Tags: verbs, phrase-request

How can I say "to say something to someone that reveals something significant about a piece of media or a piece of software"?
Should I say "to spoiler", "to do a spoiler", "to spoil"…? Are both correct?

Answer (score 3):

It's used mainly as a noun: "I gave a short description of the movie to my friend. Unfortunately, my description contained a **spoiler**".

However, Wiktionary [says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spoil#Verb) that you can also use the verb **spoil** in this sense:

> **to spoil** (transitive) To reveal the ending of (a story etc.); to ruin (a surprise) by exposing it ahead of time.
>
> *"These include a brief but showstopping (and trailer-revealed) scene where Vanellope crashes a Disney Princess reunion, packed with gags and references that should send both young and old fans into paroxysms of glee. The princess confab also leads into a scene featuring Vanellope and the cast of Slaughter Race that probably shouldn’t be **spoiled**."*